# Sencha Touch 2 instantiating a component with a background image

Tags: sencha-touch-2, stylesheet, loading, synchronous

I'm working with `Sencha Touch 2` components now.

I'm facing the following issue:

I set a background image to my components using stylesheets. My whole scene is made up of several components / containers having background images. When I instantiate my scene - the image loading process is asynchronous - i.e. my scene is displayed and then later images in the scene are loaded and displayed.

I would like to know how to wait until all my images are loaded and then display my scene. In fact, I can use `Ext.Img` class and its `load` event, but this is what I don't want to do. I need to style my images (as backgrounds) using stylesheets.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are small try embedding them as base64 encoded strings. And use them like

```
background: transparent url(data:image/png;base64,LONG-STRING-OF-BASE64-TEXT)
```

in the css.

Comment: Thanks - this should work! Unfortunately I'm working with quite large images like backgrounds for my scenes etc. But thanks a lot! I will use this approach for small images.

Comment: Well using the above approach will increase the size of the app. But i think most users will prefer speed over size. This link might help too http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317

Answer (score 0):

For adding background image on different components/containers define your **CSS** like this:-

```
 .x-panel{
   background:url(image.jpg)no-repeat center;
  }

 .x-scroll-container{
  background:url(image.jpg)no-repeat center;
  }
  .x-tab.panel{
   background:url(image.jpg)no-repeat center;
  }
```

Include this **CSS** in your **index.html** in the **head** section :-

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK and thanks. But I don't think you have fully understood my question. I don't want to set background images to default components. I want to set background images to my custom components and be able to process an event when the images are loaded / displayed. I know how to use CSS and how to include it to my project (using app.json not direct link to index).